# Jmeter- Same user details is displaying in invoice

Tags: jmeter

Same user details is displaying in invoice even after removing it from csv file and passing unique customer I'd when jmeter script is executed ...can anyone reply what's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-handle-correlation-in-jmeter).

When you record user actions using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) it catches requests "as they are" including i.e. technical ID of the user so despite you're logging in under different authority you're sending the ID of the user used for recording and it results in generating the invoice under other credentials (which indicates an issue in your software as it should not be possible to impersonate other authority)

So use [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to check each and every request and response, this way you will see where JMeter script starts misbehaving and identify the responsible request parameter or even [HTTP Header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided all the details here but as Dmitri stated at first point this will be due to incorrect parameterization.

1. Check that you are providing correct CSV file.
2. Check that the variable name you have parametrized in your script is correct.

Comment: Csv file variables are correct itself ...even I'm getting mails for multiple email I'd entered in csv file only thing is the user details is displaying same for all the order placed in INVOICE even though particular user details is removed from csv file

Comment: Though you have not provided all the details like you request, test plan . Looks like the script is not parameterized correctly. Are you parameterizing all the user details in the request that you are sending? If it is hardcoded it will send the same details every time you make a request.